# How do I convert a STAN model file to a graphviz DOT file or another graphical representation?

Tags: graphviz, hierarchical-data, graph-visualization, bayesian-networks, stan

I have a STAN file describing an hierarchical model. I would like to visualize this hierarchy with all parameters by converting the STAN code to a Graphviz DOT file. Another graphical representation will do fine as well.

Consider the following small example:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> J; // number of items
  int<lower=0> y[J]; // number of successes for j
  int<lower=0> n[J]; // number of trials for j
}
parameters {
  real<lower=0,upper=1> theta[J]; // chance of success for j
  real<lower=0,upper=1> lambda; // prior mean chance of success
  real<lower=0.1> kappa; // prior count
}
transformed parameters {
  real<lower=0> alpha; // prior success count
  real<lower=0> beta; // prior failure count
  alpha <- lambda * kappa;
  beta <- (1 - lambda) * kappa;
}
model {
  lambda ~ uniform(0,1); // hyperprior
  kappa ~ pareto(0.1,1.5); // hyperprior
  theta ~ beta(alpha,beta); // prior
  y ~ binomial(n,theta); // likelihood
}
generated quantities {
  real<lower=0,upper=1> avg; // avg success
  int<lower=0,upper=1> above_avg[J]; // true if j is above avg
  int<lower=1,upper=J> rnk[J]; // rank of j
  int<lower=0,upper=1> highest[J]; // true if j is highest rank
  avg <- mean(theta);
  for (j in 1:J)
  above_avg[j] <- (theta[j] > avg);
  for (j in 1:J) {
    rnk[j] <- rank(theta,j) + 1;
    highest[j] <- rnk[j] == 1;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to parse this and convert it into a DOT language like file that I can draw to visualize the hierarchy?

I googled around a lot and the closest thing I could find to a parser was inside the http://gephi.github.io/ project.. Not sure if that helps.

What I want to end up with is something similar to this:
[image: Kruschke]

Answer (score 2):

There is no tool for that in the Stan repository. Part of the reason is, unlike the BUGS family, such a graph is not necessary for Stan to operate. But they are nice visualization tools, so if you wrote a converter I'm sure there would be interest in using it. My guess is the path of least resistance would involve converting the .stan file to the format expected by PyMC and using their [graphing](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html#graphing-models) capabilities.

Comment: I'll do some work on it and see what I come up with. Will keep you posted!